# React Native map function could not use function in the same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So here is the code:

```
export default SomeClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    _FunctionA = () => {
        // Do something
    }

    render() {
        const arr = ['1', '2'];

        const buttons = arr.map(function(v, i) {
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._FunctionA}></TouchableOpacity>
            );
        });

        return(
            <View>
                { buttons }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is why can't I call functionA in the same class inside the map function, I know that there is a problem with this._FunctionA which is not referring to the correct function, but I could not find how and what is the method to call the Function from the map function.

Comment: use arrow function here: `arr.map((v, i) => {`, for detail check the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the map function, `this` takes another value, `this` doesn't reference class anymore, so in your render function you must reference the class in a var:

```
render() {
        const arr = ['1', '2'];
        let that = this;
        const buttons = arr.map(function(v, i) {
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={that._FunctionA}></TouchableOpacity>
            );
        });

        return(
            <View>
                { buttons }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Damn, spent hours to solve this, thank you so much sir! =D

Comment: can't accept answer till 4 mins later, will accept it then =)